# Cloudflare Workers Geolocation

Tags: geolocation, state, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

We have an Cloudflare Enterprise plan and want to pass in the regionCode (state abbreviation) into the header response back to the client. The Cloudflare request is req.cf.regionCode but for whatever reason I constantly get an error when I try to assign it to a variable so there is something wrong with the syntax.

Ultimately the header output should be:

state: CA (would show the state abbreviation from the client's IP lookup, in this case it would be California)

```
addEventListener("fetch", event => {
  event.respondWith(fetchAndReplace(event.request))
})

async function fetchAndReplace(request) {
  
  const res = await fetch(request)
  let modifiedHeaders = new Headers() 
  let state = (req.cf.regionCode)
  

  modifiedHeaders.set('Content-Type', 'text/html')
  modifiedHeaders.append('Pragma', 'no-cache')
  modifiedHeaders.append("state", `${state}`) 


  //Return maint page if you're not calling from a trusted UA
  if (request.headers.get("User-Agent") !== "Preprod") 
  {
    // Return modified response.
    return new Response(maintPage, {
      status: 503,
      headers: modifiedHeaders
    })
  }
  else //Allow users from trusted into site
  {
    //Fire all other requests directly to our WebServers
    return fetch(request)
  }
}

let maintPage = `
This is a test
`;
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: For one, you're using `req.cf.regionCode` while `req` variable was never declared. You probably want to reference `request.cf.regionCode` instead.